# how to get price of gold and silver from XML and make it upload each 3 second

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery

I have this XML file I try to load prices of gold and silver and update it  each 4 second I try this using this line to get the child element of parent with attr = "Gold Canadian $" but no use working  update I try to to get silver price and I could not it will remove the gold price ??

> goldBid = $(this).find("name[Gold Canadian
>   $]").children('bid').text();

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <MyFeed Provider="FastMarkets">
      <XAUCAD name="Gold Canadian $">
        <bid_time>20140117024711</bid_time>
        <bid>1359.27</bid>
      </XAUCAD>
      <XAGCAD name="Silver Canadian $">
        <bid_time>20140117024709</bid_time>
        <bid>22.02</bid>
      </XAGCAD>
    </MyFeed> 
    update 
    $(function () {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "XMLFile1.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {

            var goldBid = $(xml).find('XAGCAD[name="Gold Canadian $"]').children('bid').text();
            $("#AUCAD").append("$" + goldBid);
            var silverBid = $(xml).find('XAGCAD[name="Silver Canadian $"]').children('bid').text();
            $("#AGCAD").append("$" + silverBid);

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: The problem is that silver tag = XAGCAD gold tag = XAUCAD  thats why your selector doesn't work because **both** of them in your selectors have XAGCAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using [attribute-selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

```
 var goldBid =$xml.find('XAUCAD[name="Gold Canadian $"]').children('bid').text()
```

and to get silver value do this

```
var silverBid =$xml.find('XAGCAD[name="Silver Canadian $"]').children('bid').text()
```

**Note:** notice the quotes around Gold Canadian $ it's needed when the attribute has spaces

**The problem :** is when you are using `$(this).attr('Gold Canadian $')` you are trying to select the attribute `"Gold Canadian $"` and not the attribute name. Also you would need an if statement when you are using each in this case

Comment: that's solve one of the problem how can I make it update each 4 second?

Comment: @Elnajjar What do you want to update? If you want to do something repeatedly every 4 seconds, then you can use `setInterval(function(){...},4000);`

Comment: I am pulling the data from xml feed url I create this data as test data on my local unit by BTW when I try the same method to silver  it did not work for silver

Comment: Did you do this? `var silverBid =$xml.find('XAGCAD[name="Silver Canadian $"]').children('bid').text()`

Comment: yes I tried it ?$(xml).find('XAGCAD[name="Silver Canadian $"]').children('bid').text();